# cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget is not working

Tags: objective-c, performselector

I'm using in a class this method to start an action:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(startRolling) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];
```

In order to stop it I'm using:

```
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
```

But never is stopped.

Both call are implemented in the same class, and the same thread.

I've used this too but it doesn't solve it:

```
-(void)stopRolling
{
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(commitAnimation) object:nil];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
}
```

What I'm missing?

Thanks.

---EDIT---

To know if is Main Thread I'm using:

```
-(void)stopRolling
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        NSLog(@"Is Main Thread");

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(commitAnimation) object:nil];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
}
```

When works ok and when doesn't always in the Log appears Is Main Thread.

Which are doing the selectors I'm launching (startRolling and commitAnimations) are animations using [UIView beginAnimation:context:)

Is possible that this is the reason?

Here the methods:

```
-(void)startRolling
{
    currentPic++;

    if (currentPic > count)
        currentPic = 1;

    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeIn" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:RDFadeInDelay];

    NSLog(@"RollUp: %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RDInitialRollUp_%d",currentPic]);

    background.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"RDInitialRollUp_%d.jpg",currentPic]];

    background.alpha = 1.0f;    

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *) finished context:(void *) context
{
    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"fadeIn"])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(commitAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:RDOnScreenDelay];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(startRolling) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

    }
}
-(void)commitAnimation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:RDFadeOutDelay];

    background.alpha = 0.0f;    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)stopRolling
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        NSLog(@"Is Main Thread");

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(commitAnimation) object:nil];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
}
```

The method that calls the stopRolling method is being called using performOnMainThread:

Thanks.

--EDIT---

I've modified the method with the suggestions but still not working:

```
-(void)stopRolling
{
    if ([NSThread isMainThread])
        NSLog(@"Is Main Thread");
    else
        NSLog(@"Is NOT Main Thread");

    [self.layer removeAllAnimations];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(commitAnimation) object:nil];

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] cancelPerformSelectorsWithTarget:self];
}
```

I've observed that if the user taps the screen when a transition between images is being executed is when doesn't works. But If user taps on screen when the image is on screen (during 2 seconds) all works fine.

Always on Main Thread.

:( I'm desesperated, this makes the program crashes because memory.

--EDIT--

Finally I've solved using a BOOL flag. But I think is a poor solution because this must works without. Something strange is happening while an animation is being executed because this only worked when the animation is not being executed.

This works for all the cases:

```
- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *) finished context:(void *) context
{
    if (!mustAnimate) return;

    if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"fadeIn"])
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(commitAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:RDOnScreenDelay];
    }
    else
    {
        [self performSelector:@selector(startRolling) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1f];

    }
}
-(void)commitAnimation
{
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"fadeOut" context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:RDFadeOutDelay];

    background.alpha = 0.0f;    

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(void)stopRolling
{
    mustAnimate = NO;

    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startRolling) object:nil];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(commitAnimation) object:nil];

}
```

Thanks for everything.

Comment: Are you sure you checked the thread? It should work... How about setting a bigger delay to see if it's working?

Comment: In several test I've observed that sometimes is stopped and sometimes not. But the most curious is that ever do the same things. I'm really losed with this matter. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Please be sure you're always on the same thread...

Comment: I've edited with more details about the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ok please add a NSLog("IS NOT ON MAIN THREAD!"); too. To cancel the animations, please use [self.layer removeAllAnimations];

Comment: Edited, but still not solved :(

Comment: So, it always happens on the main thread and you remove all animations... When you observer the times it stopped have you logged times? Like the time when it actually happen and the time when it told it to cancel?

Comment: I think the problem is by that way, something happens when the performs are removed and the animation is being executed. I think the methods are removed just is ending and the "loop" restarts again. Thanks 4 the interest!!! :)

Comment: hi! any solution on this?? I'm having the same problem..

Answer (score 4):

change the arguments passed to both the methods as shown,

```
[self performSelector:@selector(SampleMethod) withObject:self afterDelay:delayTime];     
[NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self];
```